# Pandas new column from (possibly) recursive function

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data similar to this:

```
labels = ["sku", "buildfrom", "factor", "quantity"]
records = [("pipe5", "pipe10", 2, 1),
("pipe10", "pipe20", 2, 4),
("pipe20", "pipe20", 1, 3)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=labels)
```

In this data, *pipe5* is a product with quantity available of 1, however *pipe5* can be made from *pipe10*, as the *buildfrom* column shows. And the value 2 in the *factor* column  means that the *buildfrom* item can make 2 units of the *sku* item.
I'd like to create a column called "can_make_qty", and populate it with the possible total amount of the sku that we can make available.
In this case, the "can_make_qty" values would be:

- **3** for pipe20 (because values of buildfrom == sku, and factor is 1)
- **10** for pipe10 (4 from its own stock + (2 * 3) from pipe20)
- **21** for pipe5 (1 from its own stock + ( 2 * 10) from pipe10)

I see some use of recursive logic here, but I don't know how to code it into a function in order to add the results into "can_make_qty".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got this far with the recursion solution, and it works with the case above:

```
def canmake(row):
    final=[]
    final.append(row['quantity'])
    item = row['buildfrom']
    factor = row['factor']

    def recsearch(item, factor):
    # Since the buildfrom is different from item
    # I need to find the quantity of the item the can build the row['sku'] item
    # And multiply it by the factor from the row being analyzed
    # I have to search it in the *whole* DataFrame list
        qty = df[df['sku'] == item]['quantity'].values[0]

        final.append(qty*factor)
    # collect the new factor
        newfactor = df[df['sku'] == item]['factor'].values[0]
        factor *= newfactor
    # if the one searched has the same name for its sku and buildfrom then we don't
    # need to go any further, else do this:
        if (df[df['sku'] == item]['buildfrom'].values[0]) != (df[df['sku'] == item]['sku'].values[0]):

            item = df[df['sku'] == item]['buildfrom'].values[0]
            recsearch(item, factor)


    if row['buildfrom'] != row['sku']:
        recsearch(item, factor)

    return final # reduce(operator.add, final)

df['can_make_qty']=df.apply(canmake, axis=1)
```